# esc_pos_bluetooth no funcionan estilos

Tags: flutter, librería, impresión, generator, ticket

Hola comunidad tengo un inconveniente en la librería de flutter esc_pos_bluetooth versión 0.4.1, la librería vincula correctamente la impresora térmica e imprime lo que necesito, pero cuando quiero aplicarle estilos como bold, o heigh, width, esto no resulta tan bien, aunque reconoce los estilos en el código no se evidencia un resultado positivo.
Aquí muestro el código del ticket por medio de un generator ya que no me reconoce un tipo Ticket con esta versión.

```
Future<List<int>> testTicket(PaperSize paper) async {
   List<int> bytes = [];
  // Using default profile
  final profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();
  final generator = Generator(paper, profile);

  bytes += generator.text("Hola mi nombre es Anthony Perez", 
  styles: const PosStyles(
      bold: true,
      height: PosTextSize.size5,
      width: PosTextSize.size4,
      
  ));
  
  bytes += generator.feed(2);
  bytes += generator.cut();

   

  return bytes;
}
```